# jQuery UI Tooltip doesn't work, error in FireBug

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip

This is my site: http://www.mottobikes.com/so-funktionierts/

Hover over the most links should bringt Tooptip functionality. FireBug says:

```js
TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function
$("#content img[title]").tooltip({
```

Of course I included jQuery, jQuery UI and jQuery Toolsbefore my Tooltip code.

Comment: You say you've included jQueryUI, yet that error is indicating otherwise. Have you checked to make sure that the paths to the files are correct? Is there another script which is over-riding the `tooltip()` function?

Comment: Yes, I checked that. jQuery UI is included via code.jquery.com link and before my tooltip code.
But it seems like I have multiple jQuery includes on this page. Could that make this error/problem?

Comment: You have included jQueryUI as well as jQuery tools hence the conflict as both has tooltips.

Comment: Downloaded the needed Jquery plugin and include it on your code

Comment: Now I removed jQuery UI in order to work with jQuery Tools -> same error